# mocking User.Identity.Name in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to write a test for one of my methods in controller (MVC4). I use Moq. Within the test method I create a mock for my repository like so:

```
Mock<ISurveyRepository> mock = new Mock<ISurveyRepository>();
```

and proceed with mocking up repository calls. First one of those is:

```
int userId = repository.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
```

So I add this to my test method:

```
mock.Setup(y => y.GetUserId("testName")).Returns(1);
```

Unfortunatelly this line of code gives me:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

If I remove the line above from my controller and use static value instead (int userId = 1) a test completes fine.

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code throws exception when you are getting user name. `User` returns security information from current HTTP request. During test you don't have HTTP request, thus this code throws an exception.

Here is an implementation of this property:

```
public IPrincipal User
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext != null)            
            return HttpContext.User;

        return null;
    }
}
```

So, as you see, without HttpContext it returns null. Thus you need to setup HttpContext and provide mocked `IPrincipal` for your test. See [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx) how to create fake HttpContext.

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve your moq problem but for what its worth, [MvcContrib Test Helper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) is very useful for mocking a logged in user.

Using Test Helper you can write code like this:

```
FakeIdentity FakeId = new FakeIdentity(UserName);
FakeUser = new FakePrincipal(FakeId, new[] {  "Admin" });   
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = FakeUser;
```

to mock a user. Hope this helps.